# Online application to interactively see OpenStreetMap tags and keys

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations

In order to find out how OSM Elements are categorized I was wondering whether there is an online app which shows which elements are displayed and what their respective keys/tags are by a mouse click in the map. I have checked out the OSM Inspector, but this doesn't show all elements in the OSM Map.

Comment: Does the data layer in the main map help you https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/30.5354/102.7140&layers=D? OSM editors naturally show all the tags as well.

Comment: You may have a look at how the data from the OSM database are displayed, this should be give you some direction https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

An Android app called OSMfocus Reborn shows all tags on elements when you zoom in enough. Clicking the tag box shows all info on that element.

Here is link to the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pfiers.osmfocus